# Ventilation: positive pressure, air from outside

Tags: ventilation

I've just moved into a peak roof second floor (top floor) unit, with aluminium windows, standard rangehood and bathroom extractor fan.

I want a solution that will reduce indoor moisture and provide fresh outside air.

I've had a quote for a balanced pressure heat exchange system, about 6k NZD. As we're not planning on being in this house for more than 2-4 years, this is too much.

Instead I'm looking at a positive pressure system without heat exchange that draws air from outside, with a manual fan control.  Such a system will be about 2,700 NZD, which is within my budget.

Will this setup provide adequate air flow?

Will it eradicate condensation issues?

How difficult would the house be to heat in winter? (Auckland gets down to about 10-15C)

Comment: Yeah, for 6 grand I think I would just open a window and turn on the bathroom fan. I could live with that for a long time. 

Comment: @ArchonOSX this is what I do. It doesn't eliminate moisture or mould in nz houses though, hence my question. Added price of positive pressure system to my question.

Comment: Opening a window furthest from the bathroom with the fan on would help the bathroom and reduce the humidity. + a portable dehumidifier will help but not provide fresh air plus they need to be regularly emptied.

Comment: Michael, if the fan approach is not doing enough a dehumidifier may be the only way since you have tried the fan and window method. A dehumidifier creates heat when running if it was in the room with the open window the combination of the fan and window method with a dehumidifier may work and still only cost 100-200$ (U.S). I don't believe just pushing air through the house would be cost effective compared to the dehumidifier.

Comment: @EdBeal previous houses have required a dehumidifier running almost constantly, and doesn't solve the fresh air problem

Comment: I am suggesting a combination, dehumidifier in the room with the open window. This would make the air being pulled through the house drier and provide the fresh air you want. Some window AC units will dehumidify and that is all a Dehumidifier is but the window ones don't work well compared to a dedicated unit (at least the one I had when I lived in the mid west U.S. Did not do a good job) That has very high humidity.

Comment: @EdBeal thanks that's a good suggestion, I will look at what is available in my region